# Python 3.6: Beautiful Soup - How to extract all the text in a div container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
[<div class="nav-wrapper">
<p class="navigation-links">
<span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.example.com/2/">2</a>
<a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.example.com/3/">3</a>
<span class="page-numbers dots">…</span>
<a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.example.com/6/">6</a>
<a class="next page-numbers" href="http://www.example.com/2/">Next →</a> </p>
</div>]
```

Also,is there a simple way to extract the maximum page number in the page nav bar assuming that the entry after 'span class' is the upper limit.

Comment: container = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class" : "nav-wrapper"})
container.text

It is giving an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html = '''<div class="nav-wrapper">
          <p class="navigation-links">
          <span class="page-numbers current">1</span>
          <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.example.com/2/">2</a>
          <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.example.com/3/">3</a>
          <span class="page-numbers dots">…</span>
          <a class="page-numbers" href="http://www.example.com/6/">6</a>
          <a class="next page-numbers" href="http://www.example.com/2/">Next →</a> </p>
          </div>'''
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
max_page = bs.find('span', {'class':'page-numbers dots'}).findNext().text
```

Comment: Thanks!

Can you explain why bs is assigned twice? & Is their a shorter way to do the same?

Comment: what could be done in the case when
     <span class="page-numbers dots">…</span>
is not present.How to extract values then?

I am getting this error

bs.find('span', {'class':'page-numbers dots'}).findNext().text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findNext'

Comment: could you put here part your html code for find? and what you need to do?

Comment: I figured out the problem @Viach
I used another method to debug.Cheers!